# How to Make Multiple HTTP requests at the same time using IntelliJ

Tags: rest, http, intellij-idea

I want to test the concurrency of an REST endpoint.

How can I send two simultaneous HTTP requests to the same endpoint using Intellij?

I found this question answered for Postman, but I am wondering if there is a way to do it using Intellij

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be implemented using [Scratch files](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/scratches.html) (the type of [HTTP Request](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/http-client-in-product-code-editor.html#)).

You can allow queries to run in parallel using the [run/debug configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-java-scratch.html):

[image]

Comment: In IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.3 (Ultimate Edition) this doesn't work (anymore).

Comment: In my case the checkbox has simply been changed to "Allow multiple instances"